# Running knitr in-document functions (e.g., all_labels) on given input file

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to open & parse a given knitr document, then run some of the in-document functions (e.g., `all_labels`, `knit_code`, etc) for a given input file?

***Background:*** my typical analysis/manuscript workflow is to create an R package and do all of the analysis/plotting/tables in a single supplemental knitr file using caching. As I work interactively on the project, I need to load in the cache. It would be great to create some utilities to manage how to load the cache based on the order of chunks & the chunk options. My only workaround is to output `knit_code$get()` for every document (within the document), which doesn't lend itself well to creating a general utility.

***Goal:***

```
some_utility <- function(input) {
  knit_doc <- open_knitr(input)
  all_labels(knit_doc)
}
```

Thoughts on how I go about creating the `open_knitr` function/did I miss this functionality somewhere? I have spent a number of hours digging around in the source code and have made little progress.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Maybe a `parameterised Rmd`? Parameters can be defined through input when knitting the document or you run `render-markdown function` with desired parameters. Code chunks can be run conditionally. Thus construct a set of parameters that defines, which files to load, what to do with the input, etc.  If your concerns is more a project pipeline, read up on `targets`. The target workflow helps also managing to not rerun artefacts not needed.  Last, caching is almost saving. Think about saving interim results and read them in conditionally based on what you need.

Comment: @Ray Hadn't heard of `targets` -- thanks! It does not, however, solve the issue I'm working on. Most basically, I would like an easy way to load the cache in a specific order, namely the order of the document. `qwraps2::load_cache_dir()` & `qwraps2::load_cache_labels` get close but not quite there because there isn't a straight forward way to extract the chunk meta data from a knitr file.

Comment: Maybe that's a more appropriate question. Is there a function to extract chunk meta data from a knitr document without evaluating any code? Or what is the best process for extracting meta data? This is both more and less general, as it would solve my problem AND it doesn't really open up the ability to use all of the in-document utilities already provided by knitr.

Comment: I am not aware of a function, `read_chunk()` does not help here.     Maybe there is a way for you to tinker with the `cache.path` argument, i.e.  `{r important-computing, cache=TRUE, cache.path="cache-sexy-name/"}` to help you navigating the cache files?        Last resort idea: A Rmd is a text file. You should be able to open & read it, and then apply some text magic by extracting the `{... here chunk ...} `.  This feels like a `grepl()` with `regex`. And then more `strsplit()` to get you the meta fragment you fish for.     Apologies for not being of more help here.